# How can i get the second image using opencv or image processing

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0, opencv3.1

I want process the first image so that i could obtain objects from the image. How can i do it in opencv and python . [it is the output from a sensor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qytYU.jpg)

I want to get this type of segmentation [processed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhL5z.jpg)

Comment: It looks like the processing was done on a gray scale image and not on the measured 3d profile image. You can try to do it with watershed segmentation. If you would post each one of the original images i can try to write a python code to do what you want

Comment: this is the sample image i got..    https://s31.postimg.org/a5d50uqi3/rock.jpg